# Keyboard unresponsive out of nothing

Tags: keyboard, hardware, apple-hardware-test

I have an old 13” MBP (Early 2011) which I use regularly but just a few minutes per day.

Today I came back home - MBP was turned on and charging - and keyboard just doesn’t seem to work.

Some keys (`A`, `D`, `S`) do seem to work, but the rest of the keyboard is unresponsive. The very bad sign is that, by pressing `J` it actually writes stuff like `adsssadsa`.

- I couldn’t do any of the standard suggestions (reset PRAM or SMC). The shortcuts just don’t work, so that the machine turns on as if I wasn’t pressing any key.
- While `D` works (when MBP is turned on), I was not able to enter the Apple Hardware Test. Any idea why?
- As read somewhere, I run `kextstat -kl | awk ' !/apple/ { print $6 } ‘` to identify problematic apps, but nothing was printed

Now to me this *really* looks like a liquid damage, but I am more than 100% sure that nothing happened. Could this be explained / solved in some other way, do you have any suggestion, other than going to the closest apple store?

I surely will, but it’s not so close and I’ll be able to go only next week.

Comment: Could possibly be a swollen battery. Have you tried an external USB keyboard?

Comment: To just verify if it has got to do something to do with the software or hardware, can try using an external keyboard and let me know